# image change with coda slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

On below link,
http://www.kars4kids.org/charity/v2/nirangahtml/program_pop/placements.asp

I am using coda slide to switch content.

but I need to change above div according to slide.
palcementCont1
palcementCont2
palcementCont3

with fade.
Any idea How to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this using hash value at url,

So check hash value ,display relevant div. that is the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure all the placement_Content divs have unique IDs.

Comment: mate i can do that, but how to switch them according to slider?